# What does the es6 { [a]: b } destructuring mean?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, destructuring

There is some destructuring going on here:

```
const { [a]: b } = this.props
```

But, what does `[a]: b` do: what does the brackets with colon do?
In my case, `a` is supplied as one of the props with a string value.

Comment: Apparently, [destructuring and assigning new names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names) can be used in combination with [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names). Interesting, i did not know.

Comment: It's a computed property name, and works just like in an object literal.

Comment: nice, I didn't know you could do dynamic key name destructuring!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[a]` is a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

> ...allows you to put an expression in brackets [], that will be
>   computed and used as the property name

---

`{ [a]: b }` is a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with [assigning to new variable names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names) using a computed property name

> A property can be unpacked from an object and assigned to a variable
>   with a different name than the object property

---

Thus you end up with having a variable `b` in current scope that holds the value of `this.props[a]`

**Example**

```js
this.props = {foo : 1, bar: 2};

let p1 = 'foo';
let p2 = 'bar';

let { [p1]: b } = this.props;

console.log(b); // 1

let { [p2]: c } = this.props;

console.log(c); // 2
```

Answer (score 3):

This ES6 destructuring syntax is very similar to the new "Enhanced object literals" for defining objects with variable property names, so I think it's useful to see that first:

Pre-ES6, if you wanted to assign a value to an object with a property name that was variable, you would need to write

```
var obj = {};
obj[variable] = value
```

That's because while both the dot-notation and the object literal notation require using the actual property name, the `obj[prop]` notation allowed you to have a variable name.

ES6 introduced the extended object literal syntax, [which included the ability to write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

```
var obj = { [variable]: value }
```

The same syntax was incorporated in destructuring, which is what your question shows.

The basic destructuring allows assigning variables given literal property names:

First, assigning to a variable with the same name as a property already in the object ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Basic_assignment)):

```
var person = {name: "Mary"};
var {name} = person;
/// name = "Mary"
```

Second, assigning a variable with a different name than the one already in the object ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names)):

```
var person = {name: "Mary"};
var {name: myName} = person;
/// myName = "Mary"
```

(Side-note: if you recognize that, in the first example, `var {name} = ...` was just short-hand for `var {name: name} = ...`, you'll see that these two examples match more logically.)

But what if you don't know which property you want from `person`? Then you can use that same new computed-property-name object syntax from above ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Computed_object_property_names_and_destructuring)):

```
var person = {name: "Mary"};
var propName = getPropUserWantToKnowAbout(); // they type in "name"
var {[propName]: value} = person;
/// value = "Mary"
```

Comment: OP's code is for assigning the variable `b`, to whatever `this.props[a]` is, NOT for creating a new object with a variable property name (which is another, separate feature of ES6).

Comment: @TKol can you point me to "creating a new object with a variable property name" on some docs please?

Comment: I've expanded my answer, and explained why I put the new object syntax first, @RuiNunes see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

An example

```
var props = {'dynamic': 2}
var dyn = 'dynamic'
const {[dyn]:a} = props
console.log(a);
// logs 2
```

Check out this page: https://gist.github.com/mikaelbr/9900818

In short, if `dyn` is a string, and `props` has a property with that string as the name, accessible by `props[dyn]`, then `{[dyn]:a} = props` will assign `props[dyn]` to `a`

Comment: You're welcome to explain the downvotes. I showed an example of it in action, and the code provided works as described.

Comment: You might consider adding an explanation (in words) that describes what your code demonstrates.  You've linked to an explanation, but links go bad.